# validation error messages in BaseController

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a UsersController'S `signup` action which gathers validation error messages like

```
if($user->errors()) {
 $error_msg = [];
 foreach( $user->errors() as $errors) {
  if(is_array($errors)){
   foreach($errors as $error) {
    $error_msg[]    =   $error;
   }
  } else {
   $error_msg[]    =   $errors;
 }
}

 if(!empty($error_msg)){
  $this->Flash->error(__(implode("\n \r", $error_msg)) );
 }
}
```

This kind of error messages I want to use in all controllers. This means I have to repeat the same code in all controllers? Or is there a way to write a central function without passing specific `entity`?

Comment: Do you want to show model validation error messages in Flash error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get model validation in string you can create a [component](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html) which can be accessed from the controller

Create a component `UtilsComponent.php` under `src/Controller/Component`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;

class UtilsComponent extends Component
{

    public function validationError($validationError)
    {
        $errorMsg = '';
        if ($validationError) {
            foreach ($validationError as $errorOn => $error) {
                $errorMsg .= strtoupper($errorOn) . ': ' . implode(', ', $error) . "\n";
            }
        } else {
            $errorMsg = 'Error Occurred! Try again';
        }

        return $errorMsg;
    }
}
```

After that you can use this function anywhere in the controller like this

```
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
    // Do what you want
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__($this->Utils->validationError($user->errors())));
}
```

Hope this will help